# Pronunciation for the words which contain the letter "i"

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I am very interested to find out a rule which can help me to pronounce correctly the words which contain the letter "i".

For example: **nine** vs. **injury** vs. **provide**... These are some examples which put me in difficulty when I try speaking in English.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong letter.

*Nine* and *provide* are both examples of the [silent E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e) rule.

In a nutshell, in many words where there is another vowel preceding the E in the same syllable, the E is not pronounced. Instead, the other vowel is pronounced with its *long* sound. This is idiomatically described as "the other vowel says its own name."

Comment: The problem is, one, there are several exceptions to the long E rule. Chlorine, have, were, are, done, minute (as unit of time, not as in meaning "small"), ... and two, the term "long vowels" is very misleading.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost That's why I said "in many words". English is a language of exceptions, but the rules still generally hold.